# Custom API endpoint in extension library

Tags: acumatica

We have a custom web service for Acumatica, that we would like to integrate into our extension library. This is a service that accepts data to post into Acumatica (multiple DACs used).

However, I cannot find any information on the proper way to do that. 
We use Web API (Api Controller) and route based endpoints, and it is likely that some registration needs to take place when the extension library is loaded.

Any pointers to how this should be done?

b

Comment: Ideally you would create an endpoint in Acumatica exposing your business logic via a graph. This help article might be a good start to help answer your question: https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(1))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=c920d9fc-8e81-4f4e-9250-81c6fb979517

Comment: Thanks Brendan - but I was really looking for a way to do this with in an extension library. But maybe that isn't possible ...